# How do I redirect in expressjs while passing some context?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to make a web app in node.js. This is a simplification of what I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');
var http = require("http");


var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Prepare the context
    res.render('home.jade', context);
});

app.post('/category', function(req, res) {
    // Process the data received in req.body
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

My problem is the following:

If I find that the data sent in `/category` doesn't validate, I would like pass some additional context to the `/` page. How could I do this? Redirect doesn't seem to allow any kind of extra parameter.

Comment: Check out express' `flash`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442716/nodejs-express-res-redirectback-with-params

Comment: Terminology matters here: there is no `/` page. There is a `/` route, which express can service, and there is a homepage template, which express can render. If you want to preserve some data for rendering the homepage template after a redirect, the accepted answer notwithstanding, sessions are your friend. They give you a data store that persists across requests and responses _for individual browsing users_ so you can put data in during `/category` handling, and then take it out if it's there during `/` handing.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

There are a few ways of passing data around to different routes.  The most correct answer is, of course, query strings.  You'll need to ensure that the values are properly [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

```
app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
  var string = encodeURIComponent('something that would break');
  res.redirect('/?valid=' + string);
});
```

You can snag that in your other route by getting the parameters sent by using `req.query`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var passedVariable = req.query.valid;
  // Do something with variable
});
```

For more dynamic way you can use the [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) core module to generate the query string for you:

```
const url = require('url');    
app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(url.format({
       pathname:"/",
       query: {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2,
          "valid":"your string here"
        }
     }));
 });
```

So if you want to redirect all req query string variables you can simply do

```
res.redirect(url.format({
       pathname:"/",
       query:req.query,
     });
 });
```

And if you are using Node >= 7.x you can also use the [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) core module

```
const querystring = require('querystring');    
app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
      const query = querystring.stringify({
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2,
          "valid":"your string here"
      });
      res.redirect('/?' + query);
 });
```

Another way of doing it is by setting something up in the session.  [You can read how to set it up here](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions), but to set and access variables is something like this:

```
app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
  req.session.valid = true;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

And later on after the redirect...

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var passedVariable = req.session.valid;
  req.session.valid = null; // resets session variable
  // Do something
});
```

There is also the option of using an old feature of Express, `req.flash`.  Doing so in newer versions of Express will require you to use another library.  Essentially it allows you to set up variables that will show up and reset the next time you go to a page.  It's handy for showing errors to users, but again it's been removed by default.  EDIT: [Found a library that adds this functionality.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash)

Hopefully that will give you a general idea how to pass information around in an Express application.

Comment: Querys dont feel really alright to pass context, as this could be as big as a long paragraph, or even more. As for sessions, that may work. but it doesnt really feel right, as this doesnt seem the right purpose of sessions...

Comment: @Dbugger Oops, didn't realize you had asked the question.  If you're worried about passing too much information to the user via querystring, it might be better to store the validation data in a DB and then query that when you hit the main `/` route.  Another option is to call the post route via AJAX and store the resulting data in localstorage or something similar.

Comment: Good answer but I think sessions is the better approach than query strings - don't expose stuff in URLs!

Comment: @user2562923 I agree, sessions or POSTs are better than GETs for passing context around.  The answer was pretty vague so I wasn't sure what sort of info the asker was passing around.

Comment: node js has 2 core modules that generate the query string

Comment: @fareednamrouti Not sure what your point is?  `querystring.stringify()` is a valid option, but IIRC this answer predates that method being available.  If you'd like to edit my answer to use these newer methods, feel free.  :)

Comment: You are right but I guess it's more practical to use one of these modules :)

Comment: honestly I don't agree with the session option since it's not the purpose of session to do so and  from my experience this can lead to unexpected behaviors but still it's an option :p

Comment: @fareednamrouti I agree for the most part there.  When I originally answered it I tried to cover all the options I could think of.  I do think sessions have a use-case for long-lasting information you may need to expose, but I concede that it's probably better to use the other methods if you can.

Comment: i see anw it has some use cases

Comment: Just letting you know... your "[You can read how to set it up here](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions)" link is broken. >> The DNS cannot be found.

Comment: I recommend using [\[Node Web Apps\] - How do Express.js Sessions work?](https://nodewebapps.com/2017/06/18/how-do-nodejs-sessions-work/) to understand how sessions work in express.js

Comment: The session concept is a nice thought that hadn't occurred to me! Great answer for that!

Comment: I liked the session hack... Bravo 

Comment: wayback url of the broken link : https://web.archive.org/web/20161119044954/http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

Comment: Just FYI the session way isn't much different from query strings. Both are public and are a subject to payload limits (albeit different ones). Also if you interpolate session values into a template, then you can say bye-bye to http cache, since the response bodies will be different for the same url.

Answer (score 56):

The easiest way I have found to pass data between routeHandlers to use `next()` no need to mess with redirect or sessions.
Optionally you could just call your `homeCtrl(req,res)` instead of `next()` and just pass the `req` and `res`

```
var express  = require('express');
var jade     = require('jade');
var http     = require("http");


var app    = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

/////////////
// Routing //
/////////////

// Move route middleware into named
// functions
function homeCtrl(req, res) {

    // Prepare the context
    var context = req.dataProcessed;
    res.render('home.jade', context);
}

function categoryCtrl(req, res, next) {

    // Process the data received in req.body
    // instead of res.redirect('/');
    req.dataProcessed = somethingYouDid;
    return next();
    // optionally - Same effect
    // accept no need to define homeCtrl
    // as the last piece of middleware
    // return homeCtrl(req, res, next);
}

app.get('/', homeCtrl);

app.post('/category', categoryCtrl, homeCtrl);
```

Comment: Buddy, I love this answer.  Helped me out of a hole there - though I really need to do more reading as my gut was crying out for me to pass req and res in as arguments for next().

Comment: all next does is call the next req handler. If you pass anything to it the function signature will change and it will execute an error handler if one exists.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. :). It would be awesome if you could even break the 'Ctrl' functions in different files.

Comment: Very good and conservative answer! Much easier and much more secure than the other answers.

Comment: This approach seems to be the cleaner, but I'm not sure if it will left the address bar in the latest path or if it will end at `/`

Comment: @sum2000 It's quite easy to have the 'xxxCtrl' functions in separate files; `homeCtrl.js` would define `function homeCtrl(...)` as normal and end `module.exports = homeCtrl ;` etc., then the "routing" file would contain a collection of `app.get('/', require('./homeCtrl.js'));` lines.

Comment: @Danielo515 it will end at /categories unfortunately, so this actually is the same as just rendering the view directly in /categories...

Comment: I don't agree you are just using the router as a service to render deferent view which will leave the URL as it's, it is bad idea to structure your code that way, the purpose of next is moving to the next middleware and we usually isolate our business logic from the routers logic

Comment: If you just want to rerender the existing page, this solution is perfectly acceptable and safe. Just be sure to update the context of other variables on that page too if they have changed in the meanwhile because calling `next()` simply continues the request instead of starting a new one.

Comment: Agree with @FareedAlnamrouti, I would avoid this - it's not RESTful to eliminate the redirects and serve up different content under the same URL.

Answer (score 19):

I had to find another solution because none of the provided solutions actually met my requirements, for the following reasons:

- **Query strings**: You may not want to use query strings because the URLs could be shared by your users, and sometimes the query parameters do not make sense for a different user. For example, an error such as `?error=sessionExpired` should never be displayed to another user by accident.
- **req.session**: You may not want to use `req.session` because you need the [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) dependency for this, which includes setting up a session store (such as MongoDB), which you may not need at all, or maybe you are already using a custom session store solution.
- **next()**: You may not want to use `next()` or `next("router")` because this essentially just renders your new page under the original URL, it's not really a redirect to the new URL, more like a forward/rewrite, which may not be acceptable.

So this is my fourth solution that doesn't suffer from any of the previous issues. Basically it involves using a temporary cookie, for which you will have to first install [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser). Obviously this means it will only work where cookies are enabled, and with a limited amount of data.

Implementation example:

```
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var context = req.cookies["context"];
    res.clearCookie("context", { httpOnly: true });
    res.render("home.jade", context); // Here context is just a string, you will have to provide a valid context for your template engine
});

app.post("/category", function(req, res) {
    res.cookie("context", "myContext", { httpOnly: true });
    res.redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: No session store is required for `express-session`. A database just makes sessions persist across server restarts.

Comment: I agree to this but however the connection can be intercepted in between redirection, how to deal with that?

Answer (score 10):

we can use **express-session** to send the required data

when you initialise the app

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));
```

so before redirection just save the context for the session

```
app.post('/category', function(req, res) {
    // add your context here 
req.session.context ='your context here' ;
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Now you can get the context anywhere for the session. it can get just by **req.session.context**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    // So prepare the context
var context=req.session.context;
    res.render('home.jade', context);
});
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but for me the re.session.context is undefined in get api call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003285/passport-req-session-passport-always-gives-undefined-on-other-api-calls

Comment: If you choose to use this method, remember to set the session variable to `null` after `res.redirect()` so the error doesn't stick around on page refresh, or another attempt

Answer (score 9):

use app.set & app.get

Setting data

```
router.get(
  "/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook"),
  (req, res) => {
    req.app.set('user', res.req.user)
    return res.redirect("/sign");
  }
);
```

Getting data

```
router.get("/sign", (req, res) => {
  console.log('sign', req.app.get('user'))
});
```

Comment: bad idea to implement it. it can affect all the user all req.app is same for all users.  we can use **express-session** instead of this.

Comment: or set the user with userId `req.app.set('userId', res.req.user)`

Comment: Absolutely don't do this - misuse of singleton values/stores (like Express's app object) in HTTP servers is probably the most common cause of security vulnerabilities I've seen, and this is a great demo of one. Imagine two users of this system, one user slightly ahead in the signin flow vs. the other: the first user just hit GET /sign, while the second user is at GET /facebook/callback, prior to redirect to /sign. The first user's GET is then logging the second user's information. Whoops. Thank goodness it's only logging. If it was keyed by unique use, it'd work (that's what sessions are.)

Answer (score 6):

Here s what I suggest without using any other dependency , just node and express, use app.locals, here s an example :

```
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        var context = req.app.locals.specialContext;
        req.app.locals.specialContext = null;
        res.render("home.jade", context); 
        // or if you are using ejs
        res.render("home", {context: context}); 
    });

    function middleware(req, res, next) {
        req.app.locals.specialContext = * your context goes here *
        res.redirect("/");
    }
```

Comment: I feel like this is a bad idea because req.app.locals seems to affect all users, not just the one that made the request. Sure you will clear the data as soon as it's passed to the user, but I'd imagine you'd still have it conflicting and showing incorrect info from time to time. And if you have to clear it anyway you might as well just store it in the session instead.

Comment: actually it will only effect the request the sent by the "unique" users, even if 2 or more users send requests at the "same time" each user will have his own request object and its locals object, that way it s completely safe to use

Comment: req is for a unique user, but req.app is for all users.

Comment: use **express-session** to send the message

Answer (score 3):

You can pass small bits of key/value pair data via the query string:

```
res.redirect('/?error=denied');
```

And javascript on the home page can access that and adjust its behavior accordingly.

Note that if you don't mind `/category` staying as the URL in the browser address bar, you can just render directly instead of redirecting. IMHO many times people use redirects because older web frameworks made directly responding difficult, but it's easy in express:

```
app.post('/category', function(req, res) {

  // Process the data received in req.body

  res.render('home.jade', {error: 'denied'});
});
```

As @Dropped.on.Caprica commented, using AJAX eliminates the URL changing concern.

Comment: As I said in another answer, query strings dont seem good, since I dont know yet how big is the data I want to pass. Your other solution is the more congenial I have found, but it still breaks my intention of keeping the same URL.

Comment: @Dbugger Use an AJAX POST possibly?

Comment: Not the right way

Answer (score 3):

Update 2021:
i tried `url.format` and `querystring` and both of them are deprecated, instead we can use `URLSearchParams`

```
const {URLSearchParams} = require('url')
               
app.get('/category', (req, res) =>{
    const pathname = '/?'
    const components ={
     a:"a",
     b:"b"
    }

    const urlParameters = new URLSearchParams(components)
    res.redirect(pathname + urlParameters)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I use a very simple but efficient technique
in my **app.js ( my entry point )**
I define a variable like

```
let authUser = {};
```

Then I assign to it from my route page ( like after successful login )

```
authUser = matchedUser
```

It May be not the best approach but it fits my needs.

Answer (score -4):

```
 app.get('/category', function(req, res) {
  var string = query
  res.redirect('/?valid=' + string);
});
```

in the ejs you can directly use valid:

```
<% var k = valid %>
```

Comment: Also to be noted, the line, ‘‘‘app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Prepare the context
    res.render('home.jade', context);
});``` should be last as a catchall,