# Express.js: Is it possible to pass an object to a redirect like it is with res.render?

Tags: node.js, express

**EDIT:** The solutions proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/redirecting-in-express-passing-some-context) are the right way to achieve this:

On a `get` request in node I can do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {
        message: 'test'
    });
});
```

And send an object in order to set a message along with the request. How can I do the same with a redirect:

i.e. something like this:

```
function testSend(req, res) {

    mess = {message: 'test two'};
    res.redirect('/', mess);
    //Won't pass to the "get"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting in express, passing some context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/redirecting-in-express-passing-some-context)

Comment: can u clarify your goals?  do you want that object(`mess`) to be sent as JSON to the client in the 301 HTTP response body?

Comment: My goal would be to pass a `message` such as `"please login first"` and have that be rendered in my view.

Comment: as far as I know you can't, but what one should do for something as simple as a message like this is append the query string www.redirect_url?message=your_message to the redirect.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution would be using [express sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session):

When you initialize your app:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));
//configure the options however you need them, obviously
```

Your redirect function:

```
function testSend(req, res) {
    req.session.message = 'please login first'; //or whatever
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

And in your router:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var message = req.session.message;
    res.render('index.ejs', {message: message});
});
```

This keeps your message securely on the server side, in case it contains sensitive data.

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that this can be different for different users as well as a different session of the same user.

Comment: Where are you calling the testSend function here?

Comment: When will that obj pulled from the session?

Answer (score 2):

You can use session like @Jeremy, or pass data like params on URL

```
res.redirect('/my-url/?param1=value1&param2=value2')
```

on controller

```
req.query.param1
req.query.param2
```