# Set Express response headers before redirect

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-headers

I'm implementing a site login that takes in an email/password combo, retrieves an API token, and returns it to the user to get stored (encrypted) in localStorage.

Currently, on successful POSTing to `/login`, the app redirects the user to the index page, with the token attached as a query, like so (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)):

```
login.post('/', function(req, res) {
    ...checking password...

    Auth.getToken(user, function(err, token) {
        res.redirect('/?token=' + token);
    });
});
```

This works fine, but I'd prefer to keep my URLs as clean as possible and set the token as a header instead:

```
login.post('/', function(req, res) {
    ...checking password...

    Auth.getToken(user, function(err, token) {
        res.set('x-access-token', token);
        console.log(res._headers);
            // --> {'x-powered-by': 'Express', 'x-access-token': <token>}
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

`console.log`-ing `res._headers` shows that the headers are set as expected, but when I log `req.headers` on the request to the index page, it's not showing up:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
 accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
 referer: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 cookie: 'ifusr=crwj; _ga=GA1.1.1933420201.1409901705',
 'if-none-match': '"1195161647"' }
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting headers wouldn't work here because a redirect will execute a new http request, you can use [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to store the auth token and fetch it when you need it

```
req.session.accessToken = token
```

Comment: So if I don't want to use sessions, the query string is pretty much my only option for passing context to a new request?

Comment: You can with `res.render('index')` but not sure if you need to trigger something in the route, if you need that yes, a querystring is your only option

Comment: Extra upvotes for if you show how to put the accessToken in the session...?

Comment: Double extra upboats for you to show how to do it in `res.render('index')` @JuliánDuque