# how to redirect and read data at another jade template using node js without using session and query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to send data from one view to another but i am able to redirect only but my requirement is to redirect and send data at once to another jade template.I am using below code for this:

**customer.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('customers', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/customers/add', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.param('name');// req.body.name;//second way
    var address = req.param('address');
    var email = req.param('email');
    var phone = req.param('phone');
    res.redirect('/ViewCutomerDetail');
})
module.exports = router;
```

Now what i want is to send name,address,email,phone to another view say "ViewCutomerDetail" but how can i do this on "ViewCutomerDetail" i am using below code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello');
    res.render('ViewCutomerDetail', { req: req});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try query strings in your redirect. You might find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context

Comment: You can try to use custom header.

Comment: @mithril_knight mentioned in my question title without query string and session

Comment: I skipped that one, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies

```
router.post('/customers/add', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('name', req.param('name'));
    res.cookie('address', req.param('address'));
    res.cookie('email', req.param('email'));
    res.cookie('phone', req.param('phone'));
    res.redirect('/ViewCutomerDetail');
})

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello');
    res.render('ViewCutomerDetail', { req: req, cookies: req.cookies });
});
```

Comment: i am not sure about it is the right way..can't we send like in mvc we send object with redirect action here..because right now we are talking about only 4 fields ..what about list ???????

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong syntax for setting the cookies. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @stylishCoder "the right way" would be using sessions, but you don't want to (or can't) use them. You need _some_ sort of storage that persists between requests.