# Push notification for error email/password checking using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I am using nodeJS and express to create a simple log in form where user need to put their email and password to log in. 
For example, in client side:

```
  form(action='/login', method='post')
      .form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(type='text', name='email')
        span#message
      .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(type='password', name='password')
      button.btn.btn-warning.btn-lg(type='submit') Login
```

In server side:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Login' });

// process the login form
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.email && req.body.password == 'pass123') {
        res.redirect('/myHomePage);
    }else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
 });
```

My question is, how can I check if user is enter the valid email and valid password (which declared in server-side (pass123)). How can I have a popup/ or a message on client side to tell user that they input the wrong username/password.

I am not using any database at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is not tested, but it should lead you in the right direction.

**With reloading the page**

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context).
So you basically redirect to your login page (or whatever page you want to redirect to) while appending the get parameters, so i.e.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.email && req.body.password == 'pass123') {
        res.redirect('/myHomePage);
    }else {
        res.redirect('/'+ '?somevar=value&...');
    }
});
```

and then handle the get 'like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Login', someMessage: req.query.somevar });
});
```

**Without reloading the page**

If you do an ajax request i.e. with [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you could handle your `post` routine like

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
if(//password not valid) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ userValid: 0 }));
}
else
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ userValid: 1 }));
```

});

where the client would handle it something like

```
//some click event or whatever you do to start logging in
$.ajax({
  url: "/login",
  method: "post"
}).done(function(data) {
  if(data.userValid) {
  //redirect to home page
  }
  else
     //insert some message into your html 
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Assuming that after the user has inserted his credentials, he has to click a button, a link etc. to start the login process and further assuming that you are using jQuery, you can then just do

```
$(<selector of button, link etc>).click(function(){
    $.ajax(....);
});
```

Note that when using i.e. a submit button inside a form, you have to prevent the default action of the submit button, specifically

```
$(<selector of button, link etc>).click(function(e){
    $.ajax(....);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Some applies for a link i.e.

Comment: Where can I put the ajax call?