# MongoDB GUI Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mongodb, express

This question came up in a project for creating a minimalist GUI running in browser for MongoDB.

How to reflect the current state of the database and update as appropriate? In other words, what are some ways of implementing CRUD with HTTP verbs and being able to have a dynamically updated page.

Currently, pug is used to generate the main page and with each creation, deletion and update, the page is regenerated and served back.

The server-side is running in node.js and express.

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want to do..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can intercept a button press and do anything you link in javascript even when the button is on a form.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to achieve is that you want a button which should submit the form on the click, and you have specifically said "using JavaScript", so let's go through that first.
Firstly, lets make a form:

```
<form id="submit_this" action="action.php" method="post">
<input>........</input>
</form>
```

On the HTML Part, make a button first:

```
<button params="values" onClick="submit_form ();">
```

We are interested in the onClick methos of the Button, as this will execute the `submit_form ()` function on click/tap.

Now, the code for submit_form ():

```
function submit_form () {
    document.getElementById("submit_this").submit();
}
```

This was specifically by using JavaScript, there are many other methods also, like, using JQuery:

```
$("#submit_this").submit ();
```

(P.S. - With JQuery, you can do a lot more than just submitting a form)

or Native HTML, In the button Markup, just keep it like this:

```
<button params="values" form="submit_this">
```

(P.S. - This is Specifically for HTML5)

Another **Important Note:** The `params="values"` means that, there are other parameters, like class, style, etc. etc, so don't just copy-paste the code, ***You might need to modify this according to your problem*

Comment: ok, but there is a need to redirect to the page when the operations on the database are complete, not when the button is hit

Comment: So, for that, on the Script that you are executing, send a header type to change location (PHP), or redirect (Ruby/RoR), or any equiv. in the language you are working.

Comment: can you be more specific? there is an express server running on the server-side

Comment: I haven't worked much on node.js, but I feel this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context