# Send same data to view in POST and GET in node.js / Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Initially I tried to use the `router.post` and `router.get` methods and have them separated in my code.

Then I opted to use `router.all`, and within the same function separate `POST` and `GET` and use two `res.render` and a common object with the viewData they both share, as it will load the same screen.

I'm wondering if this is a good approach to it and how this is usually done in node.js / express.js:

```
router.all('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    var viewData = {
        data1: Demo.getdata(1),
        data2: Demo.getdata(2),
        data3: Demo.getdata(3),
        data4: Demo.getdata(4)
    };

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        request.get({
            uri: res.locals.baseUrl + '/getData',
            qs: {
                param1: param1
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                viewData.message = 'There was a problem!!';
            }
            else{
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                viewData.message = 'Good job!!';
                viewData.moreData= data.moreData;
            }
            res.render('settings/profile', viewData);
        });

    }
    else{
        res.render('settings/profile', viewData);
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest keeping it separate as I have mostly seen people explicitly define methods on a particular routes and define their callbacks or usecases. if you use `router.all` that particular route will be available for all the http methods. Using and if-else within that one callback will make your code dirty.

Comment: What would you do with the common data. A middleware ? A function? Isn't that also worse in terms of readability ?

Comment: You can use a middleware or function both which ever fits your case best. I personally use middlewares.

Comment: @RohailNajam so you suggest passing the data between the middleware the the `post` and `get` methods by using the `req` variable ?

Comment: yes you can place your data like this `req.viewData` and then receive it in your API callback or usercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest in your case is keeping them separated because they have nothing (almost) in common.

What I would do to avoid copy/pasting code is make `router.post('/profile', ...)` call `res.redirect("/profile");` so that it would fallback to the `GET` when needed.

Comment: The POST modifies the data I pass to the view. (as seen in he request callback) 
As far as I know you can not pass data on a redirect unless you [do some kind of hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19038048/1081396) (which looks pretty ugly to me!)

Comment: Don't you want to save the data in any way ?

Comment: Then, you could modify the data and pass it onto another middleware, maybe. And this middleware would do the `res.render`. Both routes (`GET` and `POST`) would use that middleware but `POST` would do some stuff before calling it.