# How to post form from NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, server, forms, http-post

I have a requirement where I have to POST a HTML form to some URL for redirection like eg what might happen in case of Credit Card Payments gateway or things like that. I mean I had to post form with hidden values and for security purposes I want to do that from server side instead of client side. Can I do that in NodeJS/Express and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What do you mean you want to do it from the server side? to redirect in express you use res.redirect. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context

Comment: I want to pass this information from the server side and not from my client Angular app or mobile app. I think redirection can be used, however I have another problem I have to receive the response from Payment Gateway HTML FORM POST, should I also receive it on the server side and how do I do that because my express server accepts REST requests?