# TypeError: expressValidator is not a function version 6.10.0

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to install and use express-validator package. I've installed the package version (6.10.0) and the code is:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"));
mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.log(`DB connection error ${err.message}`);
});

const postRoutes = require("./routes/post");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use("/", postRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`A Node Js API is listening on poty: ${port}`);
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: expressValidator is not a function
```

Comment: The way you're using it doesn't match with [the documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). So that's likely to be the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate [express-validator-error-expressvalidator-is-not-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733975/express-validator-error-expressvalidator-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @GhoulAhmed this is another express-validator version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express Validator Error: expressValidator is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733975/express-validator-error-expressvalidator-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is another express-validator version

Comment: @galleshem that would only matter if they totally changed the package API to now be a function, which your error suggests they haven't done. The point is you're using it wrong, it's unclear why you thought this *would* work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe [Probably the legacy API](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/5.2.0/legacy-api.html), which appears to have been removed in 6.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts makes sense, but unless they went back to it between 6.0 and 6.10 I don't see why the OP would think the version so important

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the problem with the version. First uninstall the present version and then install the older version that supports app.use(expressValidator()); syntax
Hint:
uninstall previous version : npm uninstall express-validator

install the older version : npm install express-validator@5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exact problem. 
With little bit of research, I found that I am using version 6.x.

The rules for the new version is changed The `[app.use(expressValidator());]` syntax is no longer supported. I would suggest you to downgrade the version into 5.x.

- Downgrade
- uninstall express-validator: `npm uninstall express-validator`
- reinstall the earlier version: `npm install express-validator@5.3.1`

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same exact problem. With little bit of research, I found that I am using 
 **version 6.x**. The rules for the new version is changed The [app.use(expressValidator());] 
 syntax is no longer supported. I would suggest you to downgrade the version into 5.x. It 
 worked for me.

**Downgrade**: 
 *First*:- uninstall express-validator: `npm uninstall express-validator`
 *Second*:- reinstall the earlier version:`npm install express-validator@5.3.1`