# How can I solve TypeError: express-validator is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mern

I'am using express-validator version 6.4.0. I am getting this error while running the server. I've tried to use custom validation and have created separate files for validator, controller and routes.

Here is the main server file "index.js"

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const {expressValidator} = require('express-validator');
const db = require('./models');

const app = express();

db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => { console.log("Connected to DB") }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressValidator());

require('./routes/user.routes')(app);
```

My validator file has two functions one for checking validation and other for returning response based on validation "user.validator.js"

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const checkValidation = (method) => {
    switch (method) {
        case "create": {
            return [
                check("first_name").exists().withMessage("It is mandatory to enter your first name"),
                check("last_name").exists().withMessage("It is mandatory to enter your last name"),
                check("email").exists().withMessage("It is mandatory to enter email")
                .isEmail().withMessage("The email must be in correct format as foo@bar.com"),
                check("password").exists().withMessage("It is mandatory to enter password")
                .isLength({ min: 6 }).withMessage("Password must be at least 6 characters in length"),
                check("role").exists().withMessage("It is mandatory to enter role")
                .isInt().withMessage("Role must be a number")
            ];
        }
    }
}

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    }

    const extractedErrors = [];
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }))

    return res.status(422).json({
        errors: extractedErrors,
    });
}

module.exports = {
    checkValidation,
    validate,
};
```

Here is my only function in user.controller.js

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        return res.json(req.body);
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
}
```

This is the routes file "user.routes.js"

```
module.exports = app => {
    const user = require('../controllers/user.controller');
    const {checkValidation, validate } = require('../validators/user.validate');
    let router = require('express').Router();

    //route to create a new tutorial
    router.post('/', checkValidation('create'), validate(), user.create);

    app.use('/api/users', router);
}
```

Comment: Hello, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733975/express-validator-error-expressvalidator-is-not-a-function) thread help you out?

Comment: Thank you it worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the version 6 you don't need to use app.use(expressValidator()); just use the express-validator utilities in the middleware, [here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/735#issuecomment-520131259) you can see some implementation in a github question:

> Here's my implementation.
>   Remove:

```js
app.use(expressValidator())
```

> Then:

```js
var router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post('/register',
  [
    check('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail(),
    check('username', 'Username field is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('password', 'Password field is required').not().isEmpty())
  ], 
  function(req, res, next) {

  // Check Errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
    res.render('register', { errors: errors.array() });
  }
  else {
    console.log('No Errors');
    res.render('dashboard', { message: 'Successful Registration.' });
  }
});
```