# can not use the express-validator in app.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

i want to use the express-validator in my project .

i require the `const expressValidator = require('express-validator')` and i using that like this :

```
app.use(expressValidator())
```

but when i run the project it show me this error :

> app.use(expressValidator())
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: expressValidator is not a function

**Whats the problem ? how  can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: Do you just require the actual lib? According to the docs, you need to do it in another way: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733975/express-validator-error-expressvalidator-is-not-a-function