# how to send jwt token to a middleware in a get request in express node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Js and web development I've tried searching the web crazy but I couldn't find a solution that could help me...

I have completed creating a project for a small lab...now I'm trying to create its login page and creating a web token using JWT...

I manage to successfully create a user and hash user password using `bcrypt`.... and successfully create an access token and refresh token....

I have also created a middleware that will authenticate the token

now I don't know how to send the token to that `middleware`

This is the authenticate token function

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next)
{ 
    try {
        // header contains the token
        // format
        // Bearer Token
        // inside autherization header
        var authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

        var token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

        if (token == null) {
            // Meaning the user has not send a token.
            // return res.sendStatus(401);
            res.redirect('/login/');
        }
        // req.token = token;
        // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token });

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log("invalid token");
                res.redirect('/login/');
                return res.sendStatus(403);
                // invalid token
            }

            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send(error.message);
    }
}
```

I will not post all the data as its not relevant as it will populate the text area and will increase the difficulty level in understanding.... I will only share the part where I'm stuck.

```
this is the part where I check if the user exists and password is correct after successful authentication then I want to redirect to the dashboard page...or the main page 

I cant send the access token to the route with the middleware of user authentication


router.post('/authenticate', (req,res,next)=>{
    // console.log("Authenticate");
    // console.log(req.body);
    // console.log("Authenticate");

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var sqlQuery = "select * from user where email  = '"+email+"' and display = 'yes' ;;";
    try {
        con.query(sqlQuery,(error,result)=>{
            if (!error) {
                // console.log(result);
                var oriPassword = result[0].PASSWORD;

                var user = 
                {
                    id : result[0].ID,
                    name : result[0].LASTNAME,
                    mobileNo : result[0].MOBILENO,

                };

                bcrypt.compare(password, oriPassword,(err,res)=>{
                    if (!err) {
                        var accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
                        var refreshToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SCRET);

                        sqlQuery = "update user set AccessToken = '"+accessToken+"' ,refreshtoken = 
 '"+refreshToken+"' where id = "+user.id+";";

                        con.query(sqlQuery,(error,result)=>{
                            if (!error) {
                                console.log("RefreshToken Inserted.");
                                console.log({accessToken:accessToken, refreshToken:refreshToken});
                               req.headers.authorization = accessToken;

                            } else {
                                console.log(error.message);
                            }
                        });

                    } 
                    else {

                    }
                });
                console.log("redirecting to login user");
                // console.log("Response Header");
                // console.log(res.header.authorization );
                res.redirect('/login/loginUser');
                // res.send({accessToken:accessToken, refreshToken:refreshToken});
            } else {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

});
```

the route I want to go

```
router.get('/loginUser',authenticateToken,(req,res,next)=>{
    // console.log(req.user);

    // res.render("pages/dashboard/index");
    // res.redirect("/");
    res.send("Success");
    console.log("Login SuccessFull..");
});
```

please help me I'm stuck in this form 3 days...

Answer (score 1):

From what i get, you want to send some data(in this case, access token) to a certain route. You can always use query strings. Check out how it is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context).

However, I am not sure if passing around tokens in non-public api is secure.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse request header to the route with the token like this.

[image]

And you can access that token in the middleware function by using this function.

```
function getTokenFromHeader() {
  if (
    (req.headers.authorization &&
      req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') ||
    (req.headers.authorization &&
      req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer')
  ) {
    return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }

  return null;
}
```