# sending variables through res.redirect()

Tags: mysql, node.js

So i'm trying to send user_id to the profile page through res.redirect().
here is my login.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
let alert = require('alert')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const mysqlConnection = require("../utils/database")

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    //Check if user exists in the database
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM usercredentials WHERE username = ?"
        mysqlConnection.query(sql, req.body.username, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err
            
            //If result length is bigger than 0 then the user exists in the database
            if(result.length > 0) {
                validUsername = true
                userPassword = result[0].password
                console.log(result)
                var user_id = result.insertId
                res(result)
            } else {
                validUsername = false
                console.log(result)

                res(result)
            }
        })
    })

    //If username is valid then check if password is correct
    if (validUsername == true) {
        const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userPassword)
        if (validPassword) {
            console.log('Successful Login')
            req.session.user_id = user_id;
            res.redirect('profile.html')
        } else {
            console.log('Failed Login')
            alert('Failed Login')

            res.redirect('login.html')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('User does not exist')
        alert('User does not exist')

        res.redirect('login.html')
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

is it possible to send user_id through in res.redirect('profile.html') like res.redirect('profile.html', req.id)?
I added my login.js code above

Comment: Do you want to send like `profile.html?userId=123` ?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar something like this res.redirect('profile.html', req.id), so I can access user_id from profile.html page.

Comment: If this is an app, why all the `.html` debris in the URLs?

Comment: Normally this is done with routing so you have a route like `/profile/:id` and then you make a URL like `/profile/1234`.

Comment: @tadman it is a website

Comment: You have Node.js code here so I can only presume you have some kind of web app going on here, not just a "website" which is a much broader term. Is this using Express?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect in expressjs while passing some context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)

Comment: That is not a proper way to resolve a promise

Comment: @tadman could you help me to get the variable from URL? for some reason query is empty

Comment: if you have proper routes, you'll get params directly in the request object. Express makes this super easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it using URL query.

```
res.redirect(`login.html?user_id=${user_id}`);
```

The alternative solution is to store it in session before redirect and get it back from session storage in the next page.

```
req.session.user_id = user_id;
res.redirect('profile.html');
```

In profile.html you can access it like:

```
// From URL query
const userId = req.query.user_id;
// From session
const userId = req.session.user_id;
```

Comment: could you please explain how to parse that user_id on different page after redirecting?

Comment: I edited the answer how to get the user_id back.

Comment: I get this error for some reason UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined

Comment: on which page are you receiving this error, after redirection? and are you storing in session or query?

Comment: no before redirection, at the login.html page

Comment: You didn't resolve the promise(). It means when you are checking user in your db or something

Comment: Can you share your code where you return the user and check for comparison in login?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230620/discussion-between-bayram-jumageldiyev-and-masood).

Comment: i am having trouble parsing the query inside of the profile.js

Comment: @BayramJumageldiyev bro you need to take a full course then