# How can i send user to home page with data?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to send user to home page after successfull login to the page

I tried rendering home page after login but the problem here is page url remains the same after login it should show home page url

`

```
res.render("index", {
                status: "Success",
                token:jwt_token
           });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You must redirect your request to your home route.

```js
res.redirect("/home")
```

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)