# Infinite search loop when the data is not exists in firestore query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing a sign-in controll by using Node.js(express) + firestore. 
I tried to use search query for `id` & password(`pw`) checking.

If the user-input data (from HTML `<form>`) is in firestore DB, Client page will redirect to `/main`. `else` will redirect back.

It worked when the data is in firestore DB, But doesn't work with infinite loop & no `redirect` when the data is not in firestore DB.

I checked the data(`id` , `pw`) and tested. But It always makes infinite loop when the data is not in firestore DB.

View code is like this.

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input placeholder="ID" name="id" id="id" type="text">
      <input placeholder="PASSWORD" name="pw" id="password" type="password">
      <button type="submit">SIGN-IN</button>
    </form>
    <button onclick="location.href='/signup'">SIGN-UP</button>
```

And the code in server is like this

```js
var users_info = db.collection('users')
    .where('id', '==', req.body.id).where('pw', '==', sha256(req.body.pw))
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          req.session.user = {
            'id': doc.data().id,
            'name': doc.data().name,
            'auth': doc.data().auth,
            'is_guest': doc.data().is_guest
          }
          res.redirect('/main');
        } else {
          res.redirect('back');
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('back');
    });
```

Comment: If the loop happens whenever there is no matching document, that means that `res.redirect('back')` doesn't do what you expect it to do. Unless back has some special meaning to your app, or a framework you use, I doubt that is the way to redirect the browser to the previous page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442716/res-redirectback-with-parameters and https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-back

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself by using `snapshot.empty`.

```js
var users_info = db.collection('users')
    .where('id', '==', req.body.id).where('pw', '==', sha256(req.body.pw))
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.empty) {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
      else{
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            req.session.user = {
              'id': doc.data().id,
              'name': doc.data().name,
              'auth': doc.data().auth,
              'is_guest': doc.data().is_guest
            }
            res.redirect('/main');
          } else {
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        });
      }

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/');
    });
```